# GCC-5 fscanf Latin-1 characters

Tags: c, gcc, printing, scanf, latin1

I am writing code to search for occurances of an user given word in a large document. The document is in Swedish, i.e. it has Latin-1 characters (åäö). I create an index of all the word in one file, and an file with all the indexes, and then a file with pointers to each. When I use fscanf to read the file, all my special chars are replaced with "?".

If input = culpä, I can printf it (the input) and it looks alright.

My search basically finds at what index the "word" is in the document, and then fscanf it. When I then print the word that fscanf reads it prints "culp?". When I look in the file where I store all the words, it says "culpä". I have saved the file with Latin-1.

Basically, my suspicion is that fscanf can't read special chars. Do anyone know what I can do instead?

Comment: Some real code would be useful. To start with, the actual call to `fscanf`. When debugging enciding problems, it is important to look at the hexdump of the data; what it looks like on the console is not very precise.

Comment: Without seeing more details I'd guess that your terminal is UTF-8 while your text file is Latin-1 (ISO8859-1). These aren't compatible aside from with ASCII.